# Typescript interface - index signature inconsistency

Tags: typescript

If I declare an interface in Typescript with a single named property and an index signature, my assumption is that the index signature allows me to add properties to the object without syntax errors.

```
interface Fruit {
    colour: string;
    [otherProperties: string]: any;
}
```

This works when I add the properties on declaration so the following compiles OK:

```
let apple: Fruit = {
    colour: 'green',
    haveToPeel: false
}
```

but if I extend after creation

```
let banana: Fruit;
banana.colour = 'yellow';
banana.haveToPeel = true;
```

then I get a TS error

> "[ts] Property 'haveToPeel' does not exist on type 'Fruit'."

I've read around on index signatures but can't get to the bottom of how I allow my objects to be extended dynamically after creation without a TS compile error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

To use the index signature you need to use the index syntax -- or use the literal assignment which you demonstrate works.

```
let banana: Fruit;
banana.colour = 'yellow';
banana['haveToPeel'] = true;
```

Comment: This is no longer true since Typescript version 2.2 (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/34?closed=1) released 2017.02.07- specifically https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12596.  You can now do `banana.haveToPeel = true;`